# How to interlopate the pickover factorial?

Tags: factorial, analytic-continuation, tetration

## **Question**

I want to be able to interlopate the pickover factorial, defined as: $$n$ = ^{n!}n!$$ where $^xx$ represents tetration. I want to be able to interlopate this function.

## **Context**

The reason I got this question because I was thinking: how can we push analytic continuation to its limit? But this was a hard bit to get past, due to it's fast-growing nature.

Comment: [link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/150993/pickover-factorial?tab=general) chat room for this question

Comment: Do you mean “interpolate”?

Comment: @MartinR I'm not sure but I think he means the analytic continuation

Comment: Do you mean $(n!)\uparrow \uparrow (n!)$ , in other words $n!$ times $n!$ in the power tower ? This function does not only grow fast, it soon gets to values WAY beyond astronomic.

Comment: Yes, peter, I mean  n! times n! in the power tower.

Comment: Several tetration extensions to complex heights have been proposed. You can use it to extend $n\$$